# How can I make make an irc bot login to a registered nick?

Tags: irc

Based on the irc docs I'm suppose send `PASS` before sending `NICK` and `USER`
But it doesn't seem to be working is there a certain order I should send things?

**SENT IN THIS ORDER**

`PASS <password>\r\n`

`NICK yuribot\r\n`

`USER yuribot a blah: yuribot\r\n`

**LOGS**

```
:irc.sxci.net 439 * :Please wait while we process your connection.
:irc.sxci.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
:irc.sxci.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking Ident
:irc.sxci.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Couldn't look up your hostname
:irc.sxci.net NOTICE AUTH :*** No Ident response
:irc.sxci.net NOTICE Yuribot :*** Your host is masked (72A6C9FC.264941B0.A6596FAF.IP)
```

This is the beginning, if you need the whole log I will provide it.

**NETWORK**

`irc.rizon.net`

Comment: The ':' in your USER line is in the wrong spot, it should read `USER yuribot a blah :yuribot\r\n`

Comment: Off-topic, but PASS is an old and non-standard way of authentification. I suggest using SASL instead: http://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/sasl-3.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pass command is for connection registration (and not for nickname identification)
You need to identify to NickServ AFTER the NICK+USER combination is sent.

There are two ways to identify to NickServ securely, the first is using the NS command, which is an alias to message the NickServ service (but NOT a user named NickServ), but the command may not be available on every server

```
NS IDENTIFY <password>\r\n
```

The way that I prefer (and recommend) is to send a normal PRIVMSG to NickServ, being sure to include the server name (services.rizon.net) to make sure that it's not accidentally sent to a user named NickServ.

```
PRIVMSG NickServ@services.rizon.net :IDENTIFY <password>\r\n
```

It may seem silly to worry about the message going to a user named NickServ, but when netsplits happen (and they do), services are often lost, and any user can use the nickname NickServ etc as it's not in use and services will not stop them as they are not online.
While some IRC daemons are now configured to protect against using the nickname NickServ, it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Thank you, for both answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

PASS on a client connection (as apposed to a server-server link) is normally reserved for connections which are in some way privileged, for example, a
connection from an IRC operator who should have their host masked immediately
on connecting.

Connections between servers of course always require PASS, because rogue servers can tamper with the shared state of the IRC network, cause instability, or do other mischief, like mass-kills.

A few networks toyed with forwarding PASS to their IRC services, but this didn't really catch on, because the [ircv3 SASL extension](http://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/sasl-3.1.html) provided a better, standard
way to authenticate users to services at connect time that didn't require
hijacking a facility that already has other purposes. In the few cases where PASS is made available for login to services, it often takes a different format than normally used for the PASS command. Because your registered nickname might not be available at connection time, services needs at least a registered nickname and password, and PASS normally accepts just a password. You'll have to look for documentation specific to the network and it's services to find the specific format required, if it's even offered.

These days, SASL authentication is supported by most networks which offer services, and, where it's offered, it will typically be the best supported option, due to widespread efforts of client and server developers to adopt it as a standard.

Some netowrks, such as Rizon, support an alternate method for automatically identifying - [CERTFP](https://wiki.rizon.net/index.php?title=CertFP). CERTFP identification automatically logs you in based on a SSL Client Certificate, which is checked against the certificate fingerprint stored in services. This is a less common method of automatically identifying than SASL, but it's secure, and doesn't require you to save your password in a script or in your settings. The specifics of setting this up differ from one network to another, and it's not always offered, but you can check the services help files on that network and ask around on help channels there to find out if its an option.

As a last resort, you can automatically /msg your login to nickserv by automatically sending `PRIVMSG nickserv :identify <password>` after you've successfully connected.

Answer (score -1):

Rizon uses a bot called nickserv (pretty common) so you just send a message to it with the format `identify <password>`

Comment: then PASS means channel password?

Comment: No, PASS is sent before USER / NICK when a server requires it (usually used for Server links). If you can connect to the server normally, you don't need one (Rizon doesn't require one)